# Ruby wrapper functions

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class that wraps other instances to provide additional functionality (a presenter) and want to now have subclasses that provide the same functionality. So it would be something like this:

```
class BasePresenter
  attr_accessor :base_object

  def initialize(base_object)
    self.base_object = base_object
  end
end

class WalrusPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
BasePresenter(:bubbles)
  #=> <# BasePresenter @base_object=:bubbles >

WalrusPresenter(:frank)
  #=> <# WalrusPresenter @base_object=:frank >
```

**Update**

I think the functional differences are outside of the scope of the question, but they seem to be a sticking point so I'll add them.

I am not trying to delegate `.new`.

`BasePresenter.new` takes a single argument and wraps it in a presenter. `BasePresenter()` takes an object and:

- If it is already a presenter, return it
- If it is an array of objects, map over them and create a new presenter
- If it is a single object, wrap it in a presenter and return it.

This is closer to ActiveSupport's `Array#wrap`, but I think the parenthetical syntax is rather communicative of its functionality so I'd like to use that if possible. The inheritance part is what is tripping me up; defining it once one the base class so it is useable on all children.

```
BasePresenter(:bubbles)
  #=> <# BasePresenter @base_object=:bubbles >

BasePresenter([:waldorf, :statler])
  #=> [ <# BasePresenter @base_object=:waldorf >, <# BasePresenter @base_object=:staler> ]

WalrusPresenter.new(:frank)
  #=> <# WalrusPresenter @base_object=:frank >
WalrusPresenter([:harold, :richard])
  #=> [ <# WalrusPresenter @base_object=:harold >, <# WalrusPresenter @base_object=:richard > ]

WalrusPresenter(WalrusPresenter(WalrusPresenter(:frank)))
  #=> <# WalrusPresenter @base_object=:frank >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing the point of your question, but to me it looks like you just forgot to use `new` to create instances of your classes:

```
BasePresenter.new(:bubbles)
# => #<BasePresenter:0x00000001ae33b8 @base_object=:bubbles> 
WalrusPresenter.new(:frank)
# => #<WalrusPresenter:0x00000001ae7878 @base_object=:frank>
```

**Update:** Mischa has already responded to your comment in about the same way I would.  [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) tries calling `to_ary` on its argument, then tries calling `to_a` on it if that fails, then creates an Array with the argument as its sole element if that fails too.

It's not clear what behavior you want; it seems like you just want to get around using `new`, which of course you can do, but it would be silly:

```
def BasePresenter(base)
  BasePresenter.new(base)
end

def WalrusPresenter(base)
  WalrusPresenter.new(base)
end
```

You could do some metaprogramming to avoid repeating yourself when creating the wrappers.  But I fail to see the reason you want to avoid `new`, and without a very good reason to do so, I'd have to recommend against it.  Ruby uses `new` to instantiate objects.

**Update 2:** Thanks for clarifying what you're looking for.  Here's the first thing that came to mind for me.  You can definitely clean it up a bit, but something like this should get you started.  (`wrap` doesn't need to be in `BasePresenter` at all.)  Anyway, here you go:

```
class BasePresenter
  attr_accessor :base_object

  def initialize(base_object)
    self.base_object = base_object
  end

  def self.wrap klass
    Object.class_eval do
      define_method klass.to_s do |object|
        case object
        when BasePresenter
          object
        when Array
          object.map{|base| klass.new(base)}
        else
          klass.new(object)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  BasePresenter.wrap BasePresenter

  def self.inherited child_klass
    BasePresenter.wrap child_klass
  end
end

class WalrusPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

This seems to do what you want:

```
BasePresenter(:bubbles)
# => #<BasePresenter:0x00000001db05a0 @base_object=:bubbles> 

BasePresenter([:waldorf, :statler])
# => [#<BasePresenter:0x00000001da7c98 @base_object=:waldorf>,
      #<BasePresenter:0x00000001da7c70 @base_object=:statler>] 

WalrusPresenter.new(:frank)
# => #<WalrusPresenter:0x00000001da4070 @base_object=:frank> 

WalrusPresenter([:harold, :richard])
# => [#<WalrusPresenter:0x00000001d773e0 @base_object=:harold>,
     #<WalrusPresenter:0x00000001d773b8 @base_object=:richard>]

WalrusPresenter(WalrusPresenter(WalrusPresenter(:frank)))
# => #<WalrusPresenter:0x00000001d6c760 @base_object=:frank>
```

Comment: I'm looking to create an equivalent to `Array()`. The functionality won't be exactly the same as `Class#new`

Comment: @Chris, from your question it looks like the functionality *is* the same. Please edit your question and show what is different exactly. If the only point is to get rid of `new`, I would advise to forget about it. It's not worth the effort.

Comment: Okay I updated the question. I'm not trying to get rid of `.new` any more that `Array()` or `Array#wrap` (in ActiveSupport) does.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the clarification.  I updated my answer with one way to do what you want, enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think what you're trying to do is super wise - there are probably better ways to accomplish what you want. But if you really want to create a new operator against a class by adding parenthesis handling, the code below does the job I think..

I'm copying the gnarly class handling code from [this great blog post](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/overloading-the-parenthesis-operator-in-ruby/) by CodeErr.

Here is my solution for your problem using his code:

```
class Object
  alias_method :orig_method_missing, :method_missing

  def method_missing(m, *a, &b)
    klass = begin
      (self.is_a?(Module) ? self : self.class).const_get(m)
    rescue NameError
    end

    return klass.send(:parens, *a, &b)  if klass.respond_to? :parens
    orig_method_missing m, *a, &b
  end
end

class X
  @@class_arg = {}
  def self.class_arg
    @@class_arg[self.name]
  end
  def self.parens(*args)
    @@class_arg[self.name] = args[0]
    Class.new(self).class_eval do
      define_method :initialize do
        super(*args)
      end
      self
    end
  end

end


class Y < X
end
class Z < X
end

Z(:bubbles)
Y(:frank)
puts Z.class_arg # "bubbles"
puts Y.class_arg # "frank"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
class BasePresenter
  attr_accessor :base_object

  def initialize(base_object)
    self.base_object = base_object
  end

  Object.class_eval do
    def BasePresenter base_object
        BasePresenter.new base_object
    end
  end

  def self.inherited child_klass
    Object.class_eval do
           define_method child_klass.to_s.to_sym do |base_object|
               child_klass.new base_object
        end
    end
  end

end

class WalrusPresenter < BasePresenter
end

class Test < WalrusPresenter; end

puts BasePresenter(:bubbles)
puts WalrusPresenter(:frank)
puts Test(:test)
```